# DDR4 memory DC recommendation to go with Intel 9900k on Hero XI z390

Tags: processor, memory

I have two possible DC (double capacity) memory for a z390 Hero XI with 9900k (at 4.8-5.1GHz); with the context of having 128GB in Windows 10 x64.

Timings are a bit different, and price difference is significantly different, even though for an intensive/professional usage, it's not this important but it can be worth a good 2TB NVMe.

I'm a programmer and few of the projects are definitely memory bound (size, latency, and bandwidth of RAM) if not CPU front-end bound or NVMe memory bound (latency and bandwidth).

Is there any specific recommendation regarding timings related to memory operations (which ones ?) and other CPU front-end bound operations/programs ?

**64gtzdcb**

https://geizhals.de/g-skill-trident-z-rgb-dc-dimm-kit-64gb-f4-3200c14d-64gtzdcb-a2034886.html

```
CAS Latency CL  14 (entspricht ~8.75ns)
Row-to-Column Delay tRCD    15 (entspricht ~9.38ns)
Row Precharge Time tRP  15 (entspricht ~9.38ns)
Active-to-Precharge Time tRAS   35 (entspricht ~21.88ns)
```

**64gtzdc**

https://geizhals.de/g-skill-trident-z-rgb-dc-dimm-kit-64gb-f4-3200c14d-64gtzdc-a2034975.html?t=alle&plz=&va=b&vl=de&hloc=at&hloc=de&hloc=uk&v=e

```
CAS Latency CL  14 (entspricht ~8.75ns)
Row-to-Column Delay tRCD    14 (entspricht ~8.75ns)
Row Precharge Time tRP  14 (entspricht ~8.75ns)
Active-to-Precharge Time tRAS   34 (entspricht ~21.25ns)
```